# How to elegantly compose two tasks with SBT?

Tags: sbt

I'd like to convert this bash expression:

```bash
$ sbt clean lint
```

into a nice build.sbt expression something like:

```bash
precommit := clean <> lint
```

so that I can run the following bash expression:

```
$ sbt precommit
```

For example, this is more-or-less how you'd do it with a Makefile:

```make
lint:
    echo linting
    touch foo.txt

clean:
    echo cleaning
    rm -f foo.txt

precommit: clean lint
```

The Makefile can be used like:

```bash
$ make precommit
echo cleaning
cleaning
rm -f foo.txt
echo linting
linting
touch foo.txt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [sequential task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-0.13-Tech-Previews.html#Sequential+tasks)

```
precommit := Def.sequential(clean, lint).value
```

while wearing a bespoke British suit, driving an Aston Martin on a country road for added elegance.

Comment: No, it's a new feature in sbt 0.13.8.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for adding it! The parallel execution of tasks within other task always made it tricky to sequence stuff.

Comment: Thanks, @EugeneYokota, this is precisely what I'm looking for. For added elegance, I'm going to pose another question. Will update when I have done so (basically I want to get rid of .value).

Answer (score 3):

Use a command alias:

```scala
addCommandAlias("precommit", ";clean;lint")
```

Comment: It works but is it elegant? Can you make it elegant?

Comment: If you don't need the output of intermediate commands, then I can't really see how you can make this more elegant that what @Dale has.

Comment: It's not elegant because it's "stringly"